# PowerShell Showing Incorrect Date When Converting From Epoch/UNIX Time

Tags: powershell, unix

I'm trying to convert Epoch/UNIX time to a readable date.  See the code below:

```
Get-Date 1472563804 -UFormat "%D %R"
```

PowerShell is throwing the following output:

```
01/01/01 00:02
```

http://www.epochconverter.com/ is showing the date as Tue, 30 Aug 2016 13:30:04 GMT so it seems to be an issue specific to PowerShell.  I've also tested other Epoch/UNIX times and PowerShell continues to throw the same date/time as above.

Comment: This type of question was asked earlier:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781697/convert-unix-time-with-powershell/21234844#21234844

Answer (score 3):

```
$epoch = Get-Date -Date "1970-01-01 00:00:00Z"
$epoch = $epoch.ToUniversalTime()
$epoch = $epoch.AddSeconds(1472563804)

$epoch
```