# Convert unix time to GMT +1

Tags: function, powershell, date, unix

I'm trying to pull out information about the last Windows restore point made.

So far I've made this

```
$rpDate = Get-ComputerRestorePoint | Select-Object -Property CreationTime
$rpDesc = Get-ComputerRestorePoint | Select-Object -Property Description

$rpDate[-1]
$rpDesc[-1]
```

The result is "20180711124151.733659-000", which is date and time, in what I presume is unix time. Normally, in PHP I would make a function($rpDate), but since this is powershell, I am a bit lost.

How do I convert unix time to a real date + timestamp?

Answer (score 3):

You could follow the original instructions from [Get-ComputerRestorePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-computerrestorepoint?view=powershell-5.1) and format the Date in the original call like this:

```
Get-ComputerRestorePoint | Format-Table @{Label="Date" ; Expression={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.CreationTime)}}
```

The Output should look like this:

```
Date
----
05.07.2018 08:09:18
05.07.2018 08:11:59
11.07.2018 07:57:54
```

If you want to get certain elements (like the last entry) you can use `Select-Object` instead (thx @Jacob), if you also want the Description do it like this:

```
Get-ComputerRestorePoint | Select @{Label="Date" ; Expression={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.CreationTime)}}, Description -last 1
```

You can choose either the Description or the Date by doing `(<command>).Date` or by using `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Date` in a Pipe.

If you want to directly convert the time, you have to split the output at the `.` and follow the instructions here [Convert Unix Time with Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781697/convert-unix-time-with-powershell)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this works. But I am unable to select the last date in the array and I would like it to also take the description.

I'm aiming to get a popupbox, that write the last restore point. If the last restorepoint is older than 7 days, it should warn the user.

Comment: Try using select rather than format-table: `Get-ComputerRestorePoint | Select @{Label="Date" ; Expression=$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.CreationTime)}} -last 1`

Comment: @SneakyFrog I edited the answer to fit your needs. Thx Jacob for the addition.