# How to convert milliseconds to date and time in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want convert milliseconds to date time follow the format `mm/dd/yyyy` in powershell, my code is below:

```
$data+= $dataList.Rows[$i]["ROOM_LASTVISITDATE"].ToString() + "`t"
```

The result of `1278504562790`. So, how i can convert it to date time in powershell, please help me. Thanks

Comment: What would be the expected date for the sample input? Also, see [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10781697/503046) that deals with seconds.

Comment: This sounds like two independent questions: "How to parse a DateTime from Unix Epoch format?", and "How to format a DateTime using a custom format string".  Both have answers already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781697/convert-unix-time-with-powershell and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249619/how-to-format-a-datetime-in-powershell

Answer (score 4):

To convert a [epoch/unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) to a human readable date with Powershell, you can  use the [`DateTimeOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimemilliseconds) type.

```
[datetimeoffset]::FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(1278504562790).DateTime
```

Your code could then look like this

```powershell
$lastVisited = $dataList.Rows[$i]["ROOM_LASTVISITDATE"].ToString()
$data += [datetimeoffset]::FromUnixTimeMilliseconds($lastVisited) + "`t"
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the offset is the start of the [UNIX epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (01/01/1970), you could simply [add the milliseconds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmilliseconds(v=vs.110).aspx) to that offset:

```
$EpochStart = Get-Date 1970-01-01T00:00:00
$myDateTime = $EpochStart.AddMilliseconds(1278504562790)
```

Comment: This will add the current time's hours/minutes/seconds/milliseconds to the provided timestamp, as you're not setting them to 0.  To handle this properly, change the parameters in the first line to `Get-Date -Day 1 -Month 1 -Year 1970 -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0 -Millisecond 0`