# How to convert unix timestamp to date and time in windows?

Tags: powershell, unix-timestamp

Every time I type in

```
date -d @1588560000
```

in the windows command prompt, I get the following message

```
C:\Users\msaad>date -d "@1588501800"
The system cannot accept the date entered.
Enter the new date: (mm-dd-yy)`
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10781697/11942268) answer your question? You should also be a little more specific. You tagged the question as "powershell", but said your are using "command prompt". So what are you using? If you use PowerShell, you can show us the output of `Get-Command date` to tell us more about the tool you are using.

Answer (score 3):

I set the unix timestamp date 0 and add it that number of seconds:

```
(Get-Date -Date "1970-01-01 00:00:00Z").toUniversalTime().addSeconds(1588560000)
```

Comment: Will that add 1588560000 seconds to 01.01.1970 00:00:00 in UTC or to 01.01.1970 00:00:00 in your specific time zone?

Comment: @Thomas is in UTC

Comment: `(Get-Date 01.01.1970).Kind` returns `Unspecified` on my machine (PowerShell 5.1), that's why I am asking. This may lead to ambiguousness when you want to process this date with other dates that are not `Unspecified`, e.g. `Local` or `Utc` ([see docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.datetimekind?view=netcore-3.1#System_DateTimeKind_Unspecified)). But the UNIX epoch is definitely UTC.

Comment: @Thomas is correct. You must create the unix epoch date as UTC, and your code doesn't do that.

Comment: @Theo OK, I've updated the answer, now it returns kind Utc

Comment: @jeprubio Is the above what I need to type into the windows command prompt? Because when I copy-paste that in the windows command prompt, it still doesn't work

Comment: In powershell? It should work. Do you get any error message?